# Get specific index of input array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with input fields like this:

```
lines[1][config][options][346]
```

I can get the last part with this:

```js
var name = 'lines[0][config][options][343]';
let ido = name.lastIndexOf("["),
  idc = name.lastIndexOf("]"),
  index = name.substring(ido + 1, idc);
console.log(index);
```

But what if i am interested in first, second, third etc. name?

Comment: Write a regex that matches your input.

Comment: Where does the text you show - `'lines[0]...[343]'` - come from; are you creating it from your own page/platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flatten the data structure into a single dimension array. First hack the string up then trim the fat:

```js
const name = 'lines[0][config][options][343]';

const arr = name.split('[');

let result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) =>
{
  let res = cur.split(']');
  
  acc.push(res);
  return acc;

},[]).map(el => el[0]);

console.log(result[1], result[2], result[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple regular expression:

```js
const input = `lines[1][config][options][346]`;
const values = input.match(/(?<=\[)[^\]]+(?=])/g);

console.log(values);    // ["1", "config", "options", "346"]
console.log(values[1]); // "config"
```

here's [explained on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Tas1TR/1), basically:

| expression | description |
| --- | --- |
| `(?<=\[)` | (positive lookbehind) Preceded by `[` |
| `[^\]]+` | not `]` one or more times |
| `(?=])` | (positive lookahead) followed by `]` |
| `g` | (Global match flag) |